# How to use both HTML5 History/State API and keep the hyperlinks with hashtags (links within documents) intact

Tags: jquery, hash, identifier, pushstate, fragmentation

I implemented [ajaxify-html5.js](https://gist.github.com/854622) into existing webpage. It uses jQuery, ScrollTo and [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). Great stuff, works wonderful. Every link like

```
<a href="category?id=5">Category 5</a>
```

gets opened in content window, like it should. Whole thing is just one problem away from perfect - when I click on a link that uses fragmentation identifier like this:

```
<a href="category?id=5#pictures">Category 5 - directly to pics</a>
```

...URL changes inside address bar like it should, but nothing happens to content. Not even category?id=5 gets loaded.

As far as I can see, this gets fired (from ajaxify-html5.js):

```
History.pushState(null,title,url);     // url = "category?id=5#pictures"
```

But statechange doesn't (from same file):

```
$window.bind('statechange',function(){
```

I figured I could sanitize every url (remove #hashtag), then everything would work... except of course getting newly loaded page positioned where `<a name="hashtag"></a>` is. Unfortunately site relies heavily on these...

**My question is: can one even use both ajaxify together with fragmentation identifiers, latter being unaffected by first?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all <a> tags with internal hrefs like this:
`var tags = jQuery("a[href*='#']");`

After afaxify-html5.js has done its magic, you can restore the original behavior by calling `tags.unbind()`.